# Python symbolic links mixed up

Tags: ubuntu, python, symlink, alternatives

Using Ubuntu 16.04

Tried to set python 3.6 as default for the `python3` command. I found what seemed to be the answer and quickly copy-pasted the following lines without carefully reading:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 1
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3.6 to provide /usr/bin/python (python) in auto mode
$ sudo update-alternatives  --set python /usr/bin/python3.6
```

This is the result:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
$ python
Python 3.6.8 (default, Dec 24 2018, 19:24:27)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.python
```

A friend of mine tried to set it back like this:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3.6 python /usr/bin/python 1
update-alternatives: renaming python link from /usr/bin/python to /usr/bin/python3.6
```

And this was the result:

```
$ python
zsh: command not found: python
```

And now anything linked with python 3.6 gets the error "Too many levels of symbolic links", like in this example:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /usr/bin/python (part of link group python) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/usr/bin/python3.6': Too many levels of symbolic links
```

The BIG problem is that if you close the terminal like like my friend did then the terminal app stops working all together. He now has to reinstall Ubuntu. And I am in the same situation, just that I still DID NOT CLOSE my terminal and (for now) everything works fine.

How can I reverse the symbolic links?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Python packages don’t use alternatives; to restore a working setup:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -sf python2.7 python
sudo ln -sf python3.5 python3
```

You’ll probably have to re-install your Python 3.6 package since it appears you’ve overwritten the `python3.6` binary.

Comment: Thank you !
I did have to reinstall python 3.6. All good now.

Comment: @StephenKitt I have tried `sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python3` ==>
 I get: `update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/usr/bin/python3': Too many levels of symbolic links`

Comment: @Bilal it sounds like your situation is different from that described in this question; please [ask a new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with details of your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

first unlink the broken one.

```
unlink /usr/bin/python2.7
```

then configure  with sudo update-alternatives

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

after that re-run your desired command